# Zend Studio copy/paste low performance

Tags: zend-studio

I have a big issue with Zend Studio 9.03. I have Zend framework 1 project and when i try to copy and paste some code it freezes for a 10-20 seconds. This project is synchronized with SVN. What can i do to remove this problem. I'm working on Phenom - x6 1055, 8Gb RAM, with Windows 7x64 professional edition.

I tried to find out with Google, and in Zend forums for this issue, but with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Disable the SVN sync, and try again to copy and paste. Let me know if it works properly

Comment: I did that before, but with no success :(

Comment: Then you have to open a ticket with them, or send them an email.

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of java installed and updated to the latest version?

Comment: Yes i have installed 64bit JRE latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I excluded JS support and my Zend Studio started to work normally again. I have multiple JS libraries (extJs, jQuery etc..) and Zend Studio was overwhelmed to check js consistency every time I change something in the code.

Instructions: In Project Explorer view, right-click the project for which you want to enable JavaScript support and select Configure | Remove JavaScript Support.